# How to setup and call an Async method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, async-await, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a xamarin android app using Mvvm Light and I've got a method I'm calling and I'd like to change it to an async method but I'm not sure how.  Just curious as to how to do this.  It's for an Xamarin Android app in Visual Studio's

Call to method :

```
    protected override void onResume()
    {
         ObservableCollection locObs = Vm.ShowLocations();
    }
```

Method :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Location> ShowLocations()
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            if (Locations != null)
            {
                var locationsCopy = Locations.ToList();
                Locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>(locationsCopy);
            }
            Election elec = IntentManager.Instance.CurrentElection;
            elec.Locations = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Location>();
            Location loc = new Location();
            loc.Name = "Alan Middle School";
            loc.Address = "300 S. County Farm Road";
            elec.Locations.Add(loc);
            Location loc2 = new Location();
            loc2.Name = "Bill High School";
            loc2.Address = "100 S. County Farm Road";
            elec.Locations.Add(loc2);
            Location loc3 = new Location();
            loc3.Name = "Cameron Fire Station";
            elec.Locations.Add(loc3);
            Location loc4 = new Location();
            loc4.Name = "Danvill Senior Center";
            elec.Locations.Add(loc4);

            Locations = elec.Locations;
        }
        return Locations;
    }
```

Comment: There are no async calls in that method.  Marking it as async wouldn't do anything.

Comment: In Java you would use `AsyncTask`. Here is the [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.AsyncTask/) on that class.

Comment: @Jason I never said there was.  I'm asking how to do it.

Comment: Also, you aren't doing anything to hang up the UI Thread, so there is no purpose to making this async. Usually those are for network calls to an API or database.

Comment: You can't just make a method async.  There needs to be some inherently async operation involved that would benefit from using the async keyword.

Comment: That's what I'm asking.  I don't think marking it async would make it async.  I've used background workers just never used async.

Comment: @cricket_007 would it be better even though this is an observable collection to use a background worker?

Comment: This method just assigns a bunch of static data.  There is nothing async here for us to work with.  Asking us to help you make this method "async" is like asking us to make this method "purple".  I appreciate that you're trying to learn something new, but this isn't a good choice of example.

Comment: I agree with @Jason. For example, if you had a SQLite Database where this data was stored, it would make sense to use an async method to fetch that data.

Comment: @Jason this will be replaced with a service call.  It's temporary I'm just asking for tips on Async or examples.

Comment: Notice Kiro's answer.  I'm basically wanting to enforce to make it easier later on... lulz

Comment: If you had mentioned using a service call in the first place, or put a dummy call to a service in your example, that would have made this whole discussion a lot easier.

Comment: I just kinda figured it was obvious.  That's code that's temp obviously no need to make a app with static hardwired business objects in it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this will be replaced with a service call. It's temporary I'm just asking for tips on Async or examples.

Once you have a service call, you can call it asynchronously with `await` as such:

```
var locations = await GetLocationsAsync();
elec.Locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>(locations);
```

This requires the calling method to be `async`, as such:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Location>> ShowLocationsAsync()
{
  var locations = await GetLocationsAsync();
  elec.Locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>(locations);
  return elec.Locations;
}
```

Which can then be called as:

```
protected override async void onResume()
{
  ObservableCollection locObs = await Vm.ShowLocationsAsync();
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  So the main parts of this are the await and that the caling method must be asynchronously.  The async call still runs on the ui thread though right(albeit asynchronously) versus a backgroundworker?

Comment: Also wouldn't one want to make the call from the original method from a task?

Comment: @HisnamewasRobertPaulson: In this example, yes, all the code runs on the UI thread asynchronously. There are no other threads involved. I'm not sure what you mean by "make the call from a task".

Comment: @Stephan Cleary - http://www.dotnetperls.com/async this has an example of creating a task then calling the async from the task object.

Comment: @HisnamewasRobertPaulson: That example is not ideal. It uses the Task constructor, `Task.Start`, and `async void`, when none of those are necessary.

Comment: For this specifically now that I think of it yes it doesn't have it's place.  I think the only thing is  I may have to use backgroundworker's inside the IO methods for everything other than the observable objects and collections....

Comment: @HisnamewasRobertPaulson: If you're using modern I/O APIs, then you shouldn't need bgws.

Comment: Yes but the abillity to spawn new threads and control their priorities is nice though and it seperate threads on multi core processors.

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary, is that the same if I call SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(status => {ObservableCollection locObs = await Vm.ShowLocationsAsync();}, null) inside NON-ASYNC protected override void OnResume()? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @macio.Jun: I don't follow the question. Can you post this as a separate question with more complete code?